# Linq Query Filter from two lists where row differs

Tags: linq

Not sure how to formulate this Linq query.
I have two lists, each of which contains HashCheck objects:

```
class HashCheck
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Hash {get; set;}
}
```

So, given

```
List<HashCheck> list1;
List<HashCheck> list2;
```

I need a query that will result in a list having rows where the Ids of the rows matches, but the Hash does not.

So for example

```
List1 =   
{1, 12345,  
 2, 34323,  
 3, 34083,  
 4, 09887}  

List2 =  
{1, 00001,  << matching id, not matching hash  
 2, 34323,  
 3, 11112,  << matching id, not matching hash  
 4, 09887  
 5, 98845}  

ResultList =  
{1, 00001,  
 3, 11112}
```

NOTE: in List2, there is an extra row, it would be a bonus if this were included in the ResultList. But I know how to do that in a separate query if necessary.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code:

```
     var list3 = (from i in list1
                  from j in list2
                  where i.Id == j.Id && i.Hash != j.Hash
                  select new HashCheck() { Id = j.Id, Hash = j.Hash
                  }).ToList<HashCheck>();
```

You can use join. something like below code:

```
      var list3 = (from i in list1
                   join j in list2 on i.Id equals j.Id
                   where i.Hash != j.Hash
                   select new HashCheck() { Id = j.Id, Hash = j.Hash 
                   }).ToList<HashCheck>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want your result to contain the `HashCheck` objects from `list2`, which would simply mean:

```
var ans = list2.Where(hc2 => !list1.Any(hc1 => hc1.Id == hc2.Id && hc1.Hash == hc2.Hash));
```

e.g. return all `list2` elements without a `list1` element that matches in both `Id` and `Hash`.

If `list1` (and/or `list2`) is very large and performance is a consideration, you can convert `list1` to a `Dictionary` and do lookups against that:

```
var list1map = list1.ToDictionary(hc1 => hc1.Id, hc1 => hc1.Hash);
var ans2 = list2.Where(hc2 => !list1map.TryGetValue(hc2.Id, out var hash1) || hash1 != hc2.Hash);
```

Another alternative would be to implement `Equals`/`GetHashCode` for your class and then you can use LINQ `Except`.

Add the following methods to your class:

```
public override bool Equals(object other) => (other is HashCheck hco) ? Id == hco.Id && Hash == hco.Hash : false;
public override int GetHashCode() => (Id, Hash).GetHashCode();
```

Now the computation is simple:

```
var ans3 = list2.Except(list1);
```

NOTE: Implementing `Equals`/`GetHashCode` in this way can be problematic if your `HashCode` objects are not treated as immutable. Some collection classes really won't like it if the hash code of an object already stored in them changes.
Also, it would be best practice to implement `operator==` and `operator!=` as well and possibly IEquatable.